# Save data to csv from different variables

Tags: python, twitter

I'm new to python and I'm looking for some help to create a loop that store data from two different variables. This method saves only the first tweet.

```
# Twitter Loop

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=search+
        " -filter:retweets",
        result_type='recent',
        lang="en").items(num_tweets):

    raw = tweet.text

    # Text processing

    clean = re.sub(r"(?:@\S*|#\S*|http(?=.*://)\S*)", "", raw)

    result = cool.api(clean)

# CSV File

import csv
f = open("file.csv", "a")
c = csv.writer(f)
c.writerow([clean, result])
f.close()
```

I made a lot of attempts and I'm not sure what's the correct way to do it.n Should I create a loop for every variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple. You need to move your calls to `csv.writerow()` inside of your for loop. That way, each tweet you iterate over will be written to the csv file(or to be more precise, the data grepped from the tweet):

```
import csv

f = open("file.csv", "a", newline="")
c = csv.writer(f)

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=search+
        " -filter:retweets",
        result_type='recent',
        lang="en").items(num_tweets):

    raw = tweet.text
    clean = re.sub(r"(?:@\S*|#\S*|http(?=.*://)\S*)", "", raw)
    result = cool.api(clean)
    c.writerow([clean, result]) # Write each tweet to the csv file.
f.close()
```

Your code can be improved by using the context manager statement `with`. This means your file will always be closed regardless of what happens:

```
import csv


with open('file.csv', 'a') as file:
    c = csv.writer(file)
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=search+
        " -filter:retweets",
        result_type='recent',
        lang="en").items(num_tweets):

        raw = tweet.text
        clean = re.sub(r"(?:@\S*|#\S*|http(?=.*://)\S*)", "", raw)
        result = cool.api(clean)
        c.writerow([clean, result])
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you know why there's empty lines between my results?

Comment: Do you mean there are extra lines between the rows your are writing to the csv file, @YoussefS.?

Comment: @YoussefS. You should probably be setting the `newline` argument of `open()` to be empty. So `with open('file.csv', 'a') as file` would become `with open('file.csv', 'a', newline='') as file`.

Comment: Glad I could help out @YoussefS. Happy programming!